# Atom editor: How do I change toggle-line-comment in the keymap?

Tags: json, keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor, cson

This here is what I come up with this far, but can't get it to work

```
'.workspace .editor':
  'cmd-7': 'unset!'
  'cmd-7': 'editor:toggle-line-comment'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me in Atom v1.3.2:

```
'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'cmd-7': 'editor:toggle-line-comments'
```